# MeshLab simplification edge collapse algorithm?

Tags: meshlab

I am generating a number of surfaces using marching cubes and have recently come across MeshLab which allows me to tidy up the MC generated meshes via the 'simplification edge collapse MC'

What algorithm is used in this MeshLab routine?